# Get the most significant bit from an 8-bit value

Tags: c++, binary, endianness

I know there are similar questions on this site, however, I couldn't seem to find something that really helped me out with the issue i'm having.

So far:

I have 1-byte (8-bits) that could be any combination of 1's and 0's.

Ex: 11000010 is my byte of data. (Little-Endian)

What i need to do is determine if the Most Significant Bit (MSB), in this case the 11, is either a 00, 01, 10, 11 and from there do some other things.

I have so far gotten the program to output the Byte as 11000010 (stored in a string) and am trying to extract the 11 from it.  (If i can figure that out then creating a switch case or if statement to check what the contents is simple enough on my own).

**I haven't been so good with C++ which is why i'm asking for assistance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about showing us your code?  MSB is one bit, your example shows two bits (11, 00, 01,etc).  You need to "and" the upper two bits, then shift right 6 bits.

Comment: `(x >> 6) & 3` will give you the 2 MSBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemes that you want to get the value of first two most significant bits.

This can be done by filtering them out and moving the value 6 bits to the left:

```
unsigned char input;
unsigned char output;

input = whatever_you_want;

output = input & 0xc0; //0xc00 = 0b11000000
output = output >> 6;
```

Comment: Why do the `&` before the shift?

Comment: true, you could also simply shift the value - clearing other bits is just more human-readable and sometimes a precaution measure

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to store it as a string, just use bitwise operators:

```
unsigned char myByte = 0xc2; // 11000010
char twoMost = (myByte & 0xff) >> 6; // 00000011
```

The `0xff` "selects" (masks) only the first 8 bits, so that if the `char` type is actually bigger than 8 bits, then everything else is discarded.

By shifting 6 bits to the right, you get to keep only the two most significant. Then, you can apply a `switch` like:

```
switch(twoMost) {
    case 0: // 00
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 1: // 01
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 2: // 10
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 3: // 11
        doSomething();
        break;
    default:
        // This is not possible, but better output an error message
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `myByte & 0xC0` instead?

Comment: What does the & 0xff do?

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's the same, the first 6 bits get discarded.

Comment: @stark I've added the meaning of `0xff` to the answer.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: `0xFF` is `00000011` and `0xC0` is `11000000`, that makes a big difference when masking bits, especially if you are going to shift them afterwards.

Comment: @stark: the `&` operator masks bits. If a bit in the mask is 1, the corresponding bit in the masked value is preserved, otherwise it is set to 0.

Comment: Better use an `unsigned char` as `char` may be signed and shifting on signed integers is actually implementation defined and may not be portable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau what?? `0xff` is `11111111`. Just think, `0xc0` cannot be bigger than `0xff`. `00000011` is `3`, BTW.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: nevermind, I was thinking of multi-byte values, since `0xFF` is a single byte.  In which case, since `char` is 1 byte, masking it by `0xFF` is redundant and unnecessary, just shift it as-is, or optionally mask it with `0xC0`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've explained in the answer why masking is useful (and maybe necessary). Using `0xc0` or `0xff` is exactly the same, because you loose the first 6 bits anyway. I prefer the latter because it's clearer in my mind. As of multibyte values, I don't understand how they could change anything, `0xff` has the same value, no matter the size of the type.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal yes, I agree. Added to the answer.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: `0xFF` does not have the same value regardless of type size. If you mask a 16-bit type with `0xFF`, it gets masked as `0x00FF`, not as `0xFFFF`. If you mask a 32-bit type with `0xFF`, it gets masked as `0x00000000FF`, not as `0xFFFFFFFF`. Try it and you will see.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I really cannot understand you point. Of course it get masked as `0x00ff`, this is the intended behaviour, to "select" the first 8 bits. How does this relate to the comment you made above "`0xFF` is `00000011` and `0xC0` is `11000000`", which is simply wrong, no matter if multibyte or not?

Answer (score 3):

First, endianness has to do with the order of bytes in a word, not with the order of bits in a byte.

Second, you want two most significant bits, not *the* MSB.

That said, here's the code:

```
unsigned char c = Something(); //That's your byte; comes from somewhere
unsigned char x = c >> 6;
```

So if the MSBs are 11, the value of x will be 3. If it's 10, then 2. If 01, then 1. If 00, then 0.

`Unsigned`-ness of the variable is important; it makes the >> operator behave like a bitwise shift, not like arithmetic shift. With a `signed char` variable, you'd want the following expression instead:

```
char x = (c >> 6) & 3;
```

Signed-ness of the vanilla `char` datatype is compiler and platform specific, and can be affected by compiler options.